# Dataframe not recognized for GINI function (package reldist)

Tags: r

I want to calculate the [Gini](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reldist/reldist.pdf) coefficient using the library [reldist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reldist/reldist.pdf).

This is my code :

```
library(reldist)

year_return <- read.csv("year_return.csv")
year_return[3:19] <- lapply(year_return[3:19], function(x) 
  as.numeric(as.character(x)))
year_return[[2]] <- as.Date(year_return[[2]])
str(year_return)

gini(year_return[3:19],w)
```

This is the error I get :

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, ox) : undefined columns selected
> ```

This is w :

```
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]
     0.04591712 0.04078667 0.04126135 0.05131896 0.04349168 0.04834431 0.04694083 0.03904389 0.04117694
  [,10]      [,11]      [,12]      [,13]      [,14]     [,15]      [,16]      [,17]     [,18]
     0.04537461 0.04692524 0.04045692 0.04696848 0.05087293 0.1713231 0.08499888 0.04396601 0.0708321
```

This is what I get for str(year_return) :

```
X       Date  .SXQR  .SXTR  .SXNR  .SXMR  .SXAR  .SX3R  .SX6R  .SXFR  .SXOR  .SXDR  .SX4R  .SXRR  .SXER
1 1 2000-01-03 364.94 223.93 489.04 586.38 306.56 246.81 385.36 403.82 283.78 455.39 427.43 498.08 457.57
2 2 2000-01-04 345.04 218.90 474.05 566.15 301.13 239.24 374.64 390.41 275.93 434.92 414.10 476.17 435.72
3 3 2000-01-05 338.22 215.88 464.20 542.29 298.22 239.55 373.26 383.48 272.54 430.05 406.33 466.19 436.23
4 4 2000-01-06 343.13 218.18 470.82 529.33 300.69 249.75 377.26 383.48 272.47 434.15 417.91 464.59 438.26
5 5 2000-01-07 349.46 220.10 478.87 531.65 306.50 255.17 381.19 390.23 273.76 447.02 428.54 474.40 445.40
6 6 2000-01-10 356.20 223.01 484.07 581.82 310.84 252.75 387.74 393.75 278.76 453.80 431.81 473.14 440.15
    .SXKR  .SX7R   .SX8R  .SXIR  .SXPR
1 1016.39 489.65 1070.72 466.36 368.62
2  971.51 471.23 1015.13 450.38 365.89
3  924.57 464.75  949.91 446.67 363.78
4  887.88 461.62  935.48 448.10 370.22
5  918.33 465.41  970.17 456.69 376.62
6  944.22 467.89 1002.93 460.26 373.81
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1be3GMRNwwfGZm8gkJi-sWJMWnG6T4nYh) you can find the dataset I am using (year_return.csv)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not post links to your datasets. Please provide a [reproducible example in r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us some efforts. Cheers.

Comment: @M-M Hello ! Thanks for you message, I wasn't aware of that ! Thank you !

Comment: I've never used the `reldist` package, but it looks like `gini` expects `x` and `weights` to be the same length. `year_return[3:19]` has 17 columns while `w` has 18. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @divibisan Hey, I tried with year_return[3:20] but still having the same message error